# How to make swift class with `open` and `public` not appear in `Framework-Swift.h`

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode12

It is working before with xcode 11 but when I upgrade to use xcode 12 I encounter this kind of error

```
(255, 1) 'BottomSheetViewController' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is definition in module 'EkoUIKit.Swift' found return type is 'void'
```

I understand that we have 2 frameworks which expose the same `BottomSheetViewController` class however, before this is working fine and we know ourself  that `BottomSheetViewController` will never be used in objective-c code. But because we make the modifier `public` and `open` even without `@objc` somehow in xcode 12 this class got included in auto-generated `Framework-Swift.h` file

Currently, I can solve this by adding `@objc(PrefixBotomSheetViewController)` on one of the class.

Is there a way to not include `BottomSheetViewController` in auto-generated `Framework-Swift.h`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explicitly hide a specific public Swift type from Objective-C, you should use the `@nonobjc` modifier on that type.

```
@nonobjc open class BottomSheetViewController: UIViewController {
...
}
```

Comment: That the keyword I want, the problem is somehow it is fail in this case showing error

'@nonobjc' attribute cannot be applied to this declaration

I don't know that because the framework include both objc and swift class that force it to treat all swifts public/open to have objc interface counterpart in xcode 12?